# Edits to question required in order to include additional tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, retagging, editing

I saw a question that was missing obvious tags just now so I clicked on edit to include them - however it wouldn't let me save the update unless I changed 6 characters in the original question...I worked around it by getting rid of apostrophes so that I can add the tags but obviously that's not idea as we're editing questions which don't need editing just to make the metadata tags clearer for others.

Is this something that can be changed?

Answer (score 4):

If you *only* change the tags you shouldn't need to modify the content.  It's only if you make a content change that it will require you to change at least 6 characters.

Also note that even with a retag you have to enter at least 10 characters in the edit summary.  (I usually just say, "Retagged with" and list the new tags.)